# Re-ordering rows based on position SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have seen many questions on SO regarding this question but none is relevant to my scenario. I am nowhere near an SQL guy apart from doing basic CRUD operations. Hence I am quite stuck with this.

I have a table.

`myTable [rID, newsID, OrderPosition]` where;

```
rID is primaryKey int column, 
newsID int is the ID of an item from another table and,
OrderPosition int to hold the position of the rows.
```

myTable will always have a total of 10 rows.

So, initially, lets assume myTable has the following data:

```
rID    newsID    OrderPosition
100    4000      1
101    4100      2
102    4200      3
103    4300      4
104    4400      5
105    4500      6
106    4600      7
107    4700      8
108    4800      9
109    4900      10
```

The expected functionality should be as follows;

INSERT NEW

when inserting a new item, user should be able to insert it into any position he/she desires. Right now, I only managed to insert the new record to the first position by deleting the OrderPosition = 10 row, assigning the new record OrderPosition of 0, and reorder the table. But client wants to select which position the item should go. In which case I assume, the OrderPosition = 10 will be deleted again?

DELETE

When a record from this table is deleted, since there will always be a total of 10 records, I need to get the latest entered record from another table [tblNews] and insert it to the 10th position (I can get the last record from tblNews by ordering descending by the date it was entered.) Since I don't know which record they will delete, I don't know how to re-order the table after a record has been deleted.

Any help, code, direction to an article would be very much appreciated.

=========== EDIT ====================

The UPDATE method mentioned in the answers will not work for me since;
e.g. user wants to insert a new record into the 5th order position. This would mean, the order position 10 would be deleted and the current records with order postions 5,6,7,8 and 9 is to be incremented by one

Comment: Just to be sure that you're aware of this: Tables have *no* inherent order. The only way to affect the order in which rows are returned in a result set is to have an `ORDER BY` clause on the outermost `SELECT` that generates the result set. Is that compatible with what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting the row, you need to "move" the rows below to make the room for it. For example, inserting on a position 4 could be done like this:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE OrderPosition = 10; -- If you want the keep the table from growing beyond 10 rows.
UPDATE myTable SET OrderPosition = OrderPosition + 1 WHERE OrderPosition >= 4;
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (..., 4);
```

Conversely, after you delete the row, you can move the rows "below" it back up:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE OrderPosition = 4;
UPDATE myTable SET OrderPosition = OrderPosition - 1 WHERE OrderPosition > 4;
-- Now you can insert the row on position 10 if desired.
```

Note that even if OrderPosition has a UNIQUE constraint on it, UPDATE won't violate it.

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55371/9)

Comment: Branko, thank you for your answer. Based on @carlos' comment can you also tell me how to implement this in a transaction?

Comment: @Emin Well, you can start the transaction, do all the necessary operations, then commit the transaction at the end. The transaction is atomic, so you can't end-up with partial results in the database (due to a bug or a power cut, for example). How _exactly_ to start and commit a transaction depends on your client language / library of choice, but I'm sure it's clearly documented there...

Answer (score 4):

Something like this will work for you, I guess:

```
CREATE PROC uspMyTableInsert
(
    @newsID INT, @order int
)
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE MyTable
    SET OrderPosition = OrderPosition + 1
    WHERE OrderPosition >= @Order;

    INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (@newsID, @order);

    DELETE FROM dbo.myTable WHERE OrderPosition = 11


END
```

So, for inserting you have 3 steps:

First you update orders of items to follow (+1), then insert your item, and at the end delete 11th row.

Similar for Delete - also 3 steps, but first you delete the row, then update orders of following rows (-1 this time) and at the end just insert your new 10th row.

```
CREATE PROC uspMyTableDelete
(
    @order int
)
AS
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM dbo.myTable WHERE OrderPosition =@order

    UPDATE MyTable
    SET OrderPosition = OrderPosition -1
    WHERE OrderPosition > @Order;

    INSERT INTO MyTable 
    SELECT TOP 1 newsID, 10 
    FROM tblNews ORDER BY newsID DESC


END
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e213/3)**

Comment: +1 because of the use of procedures to make the transactions.

Comment: @Clon How does "the use of procedures make the transactions"?

Comment: Hi @Nenad, nice answer (+1). Just one small nitpick: in the first case you can just delete the last row (by doing it before UPDATE) instead of updating _and_ deleting it.

Comment: @Branko Dijitrijevic - You're right. I wanted to say something like: +1 because of the use of procedures to operate your database through them, thus creating an API which encapsulates your data and operations. This gives independence between application and database, and ensures that you don't forget any steps in the action of inserting or deleting records.

Comment: @Nenad, thank you for the detailed answer both your and Branko's answers work but he answered first so had to accept his. But gave you a +1.

Answer (score 0):

> when inserting a new item, user should be able to insert it into any
>   position he/she desires. Right now, I only managed to insert the new
>   record to the first position by deleting the OrderPosition = 10

The order of data when returned from database is determined by the sql query - I assume the sql query ayou are referring to has "order by OderPosition".

You can insert,update any record any way you want.

```
update mytable set newsID = "newid" where orderposition=10
```

this doesn;t make sense:

> When a record from this table is deleted, since there will always be a
>   total of 10 records

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my mistake by not mentioning it but when the site is started to be used for the first time, the said table would be empty, hence the update method won't do any good..

Comment: update, insert, delete its all pretty simple - the most basic of sql operations

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the problem is but will try to help.

First if the ColumnPosition is to have only 10 different numbers it should have the constraint unique on it (to avoid software mistakes).

Now say you want to do this for position five, it would have to look like:
delete from myTable where ColumnPosition = 5;
insert into myTable (newsID, OrderPosition) values (val, 5);

This should occur within a transaction and it's assuming your rID is a auto-incremented ID.

Comment: Still it's not very clear what you want to achiv Emin :), it seems you want to change the items in a given position while maintaining the order, is it not this?

Comment: Carlos, give it to my bad english in not being quite good at expressing myself :) But, @branko-dimitrijevic's answer explains more or less what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to implement it to see what other issues might arise.

Comment: Ok, but if you follow @branko-dimitrijevic's answer please remember to implement it within a transaction for a more secure and correct functionality.

Comment: Carlos look at my question and tell me you believe I know what transactions are :) I am going to kill our sql guy since he disappeared for a holiday and i have to go through all this!