# Insert data in sqlite always at first row

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite and I want to have exactly 50 entries, not more. There can be less. The list should be work as FIFO. So I add an entry always at position id=1. If the list exceed the size of 50, the entry with id=51 will be removed. How can I do this?

```
id | entry
---------------
1  First
2  Second
.  .....
50 Fiftieth
```

add a new entry:

```
id | entry
---------------
1  NewFirst  
2  First
3  Second
.  .....
50 Fourtynineth
```

Comment: you need to move the rows below to make the room for it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271727/re-ordering-rows-based-on-position-sql-server Check This

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trigger for that.
It will do a specific task every time you make an update, insert or delete.

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name [BEFORE|AFTER] event_type  (insert,update,delete) ON table_name BEGIN 
-- Trigger logic
END;

Take a look at this site: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_triggers.htm